# NodeJS axios fails with self sign certificate while cURL succeeds with same "ca bunlde"

Tags: node.js, ssl, x509certficiate2

I am trying to use nodejs with axios library. I use the following code to query some URL:

```
const tryAxios = async () => {
    const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        ca: `${await fs.promises.readFile('/etc/tal_the_king/something.pem', { encoding: 'utf-8' })}`,
        keepAlive: false,
    });

    const x = await axios.get('https://www.example.com', {
        httpssAgent: httpAgent,
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Expires': '0',
        },
    });

    console.log(x);
};
```

It fails for:

```
(node:76565) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1507:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:76565) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:76565) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

Then I try the same with cURL:

```bash
sudo curl -v  --cacert '/etc/tal_the_king/something.pem'  https://www.example.com
```

This query succeeds:

```
   Trying 93.184.216.34:443...
* Connected to www.example.com (93.184.216.34) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/tal_the_king/something.pem
*  CApath: none
```

Where am I wrong?

ThAnK yoU

Comment: What is the content of the CA file? Specifically - has the certificate in this file has basic constraints CA:TRUE (try `openssl x509 -in file.pem -text` to see details)? What is the version and TLS stack used in curl (see `curl -V`)?

Comment: yes, 
  X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical

And curl -V iscurl 7.79.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0) libcurl/7.79.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.45.1

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ httpsAgent: httpAgent, headers: ... }` in the request config instead of `{ httpAgent, headers: ...}` ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, I fixed it already but it yet to fail

Comment: Please update your question then to reflect what your are exactly doing.

Comment: the current failing code is:


const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  ca: `${await fs.promises.readFile(certfile, { encoding: 'utf-8' })}`,
  keepAlive: false,
 });

 const x = await axios.get('https://www.example.com', {
  httpsAgent,
  headers: {
   'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
   'Pragma': 'no-cache',
   'Expires': '0',
  },
 });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245039/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-saar-yoffe).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?